# How do I print JSON results from async.get() on urls in python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, asynchronous, python-requests

In python, using async from requests and get, I'd like to print the responses from async.map()

```
from requests import async

url_list = ['abc.com','xyz.com']
rs = [async.get(u) for u in url_list]
a = async.map(rs)
print a
```

This gives me the result

```
[<Response[200]>,<Response[200]>]
```

I'd like to print the JSON responses obtained from the async.map from the url's Thanks

Comment: What is `async`?

Comment: What do you get currently?

Comment: @roganjosh [<Response [200]>, <Response[200]>]

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be to add a .text

```
a = async.map(rs)
print a.text
```

will give you the JSON within the response.